# SQL query by adding two columns in where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table that contains two scores:

- scoreA
- scoreB

I am trying to make a SQL query by adding these two values, such as

```
SELECT *,(scoreA+scoreB) as scoreC FROM data WHERE scoreC > 100 ORDER BY scoreC DESC
```

However, it shows an error:

```
ERROR: Unknown column 'scoreC' in 'where clause'
```

Is there any way to work around for this?

P.S. the reason I don't add a new column for scoreC is because scoreA/scoreB are updated continuously by other cron jobs and if I want to calculate scoreC, I need to make extra queries/updates for scoreC, which I would like to avoid to save system resources. However, if it is the only way to calculate scoreC by another cron job, I am also ok with it if it's the only solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL supports a non-standard extension that allows you to use the `having` clause in this case:

```
SELECT *, (scoreA+scoreB) as scoreC
FROM data
HAVING scoreC > 100
ORDER BY scoreC DESC;
```

Let me emphasize that this is MySQL-specific.  For a simple expression such as this, I would just put the formula in the `where` clause. But sometimes the expression can be quite complicated -- say a distance formula or complex `case` or subquery.  In those cases, the `having` extension is actually useful.

And, you don't need the formula in the `order by` clause.  MySQL allows column aliases there.

Comment: make sure you keep clauses in order if you have `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER` clauses, Which is: `WHERE`->`GROUP BY`=>`HAVING`=>`ORDER BY`

Answer (score 6):

In most ANSI compliant RDBMS, you won't be able to use the derived column `ScoreC` in the where clause. However, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT *, (scoreA + scoreB) as scoreC 
   FROM data 
) SummedScores
WHERE SummedScores.scoreC > 100 
ORDER BY SummedScores.scoreC DESC;
```

where `SummedScores` is a [derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f0120/1)

Comment: could you explain what `x` is here. +1

Comment: Thanks @samshers - my answer needed some clarification and a reference to the docs.. I've renamed the alias to be more meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the calculated fields name in where and order by but you can use the formula:

```
SELECT scorea + scoreb FROM data WHERE scorea+scoreb > 100 order BY scorea+scoreb
```

You also could create a view with the field scorec.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,(scoreA+scoreB) as scoreC 
FROM data 
WHERE (scoreA+scoreB) > 100 
ORDER BY (scoreA+scoreB) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HAVING` clause for this.

```
SELECT *,(scoreA+scoreB) as scoreC 
FROM data 
HAVING scoreC > 100
ORDER BY scoreC DESC;
```

[From documentation:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)
"The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well."

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [**HAVING**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause

```
SELECT *,(scoreA+scoreB) as scoreC 
FROM data HAVING scoreC > 100 
ORDER BY scoreC DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

now it's possible to add condition with column names in where clause like this

```
select * from hotel_rooms where (total_pax + extra_beds >= 3);
```

Comment: Don't know the reason but this doesn't works, I'm using mysql db.